# If input box goes over character limit, have span tag message display

Tags: html, css, input, coffeescript, message

I have a Headline input box that has a limit of 3 characters for the user to type in.  After the user has reached the limit of 3 characters and is no longer able to type, I would like the span message listed below to display in red, "Headline must be under 3 characters."

Via a CoffeeScript function, I am trying to add a class on change that should display the span message below in red; however it is not working.  I have provided a Fiddle for this issue.  In addition, I have displayed an image of what I would like my function to display.  If anyone can help I would really appreciate it!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/missybur/9ermgamb/1/)

[image: What I would like span message to display]

```
<label htmlFor="request[title]">Headline</label>
        <input name="request[title]" id="headline_input" onChange= "headline_input_max" maxLength="3" type="text"
               placeholder="Give your request a title"
               required />
        <span id="title_over_limit_text">Headline must be under 3 characters.</span>

 $ ->
  $('#headline_input').change ->
    if $(this).val().length > 3
        $('#title_over_limit_text').addClass('title_over_limit_text_display')


#title_over_limit_text {
  display: none;
}

.title_over_limit_text_display {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Where is your `headline_input_max` function? Also, you need to show your message, `.title_over_limit_text_display {
  color: red; display: inline;
}`

Comment: I forgot to take that line out.  I tried creating a 'headline_input_max' function, but it still was not displaying the "Headline must be under 3 characters." span message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO this below : If it doesn't work call my attention.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <input name="requesttitle" id="headline_input" onkeyup="seee()" type="text" placeholder="Give your request a title" required />
        <span id="title_over_limit_text" style="display:none;">Headline must be under 3 characters.</span>

       <script>
        function seee(){
   var textval = $("#headline_input").val().length;
  //  alert (textval); to see count of the text number
    if (textval > 3){
      $("#title_over_limit_text").show();
      //if maybe you want to run ajax request here you can do that.
      return false;
     } else {
     $("#title_over_limit_text").hide();
     return false;
   }
   }
       </script> 

#title_over_limit_text {
  display: none;
}

.title_over_limit_text_display {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shasha, That unfortunately did not work.  I am trying to avoid using any inline JavaScript.  I would like to have a separate CoffeeScript function that would be able to resolve this problem.  If you have any other ideas, please let me know!

Comment: @MissyBur Cofeescripts are long codes, but let me re-edit my code should work.

Comment: @MissyBur another reason why it would not work is because you have maxlength so it can never be more than 3 characters, and also my script only works for more than 3 characters, i mean here if (textval > 3){ } else { } in my code area.

Comment: Good point.  Should I take the 'maxLength = 3' out of the HTML so the CoffeeScript function will know once 3 characters have been typed into the input box?

Comment: I will for sure upvote you if you can help me with this!!  I'm new to CoffeeScript so this has been quite challenging.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MissyBur fixed the code up that should work, as for cofee scripts i really dont know much on that.

Comment: I see how your answer makes sense, but I'm having trouble converting it to CoffeeScript and get it working.  I'll let you know my solution if I am able to get it to work.